# How can I deploy Visio Web drawing with connection to a SharePoint list using SharePoint feature and solution?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio-services

How can I deploy Visio Web drawing with connection to a SharePoint list using SharePoint feature and solution? Can Anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save directly to the SharePoint document library as .vwd.

[image]